# Dealing with different object types while iterating through an NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsarray, nsdictionary

```
for (NSArray *values in [serializedJSON allValues])
```

Sometimes the values in serializedJSON will be arrays, and sometimes they will be NSDictionaries. I would like to discriminate against one of them so I don't get any errors like I am now. So I only want the returning values in this case to be NSArrays, while in a second case I would only want them to be NSDictionaries.

Thanks in advanced!

If you need more info let me know

Comment: [isKindOfClass](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isKindOfClass:)

Comment: You can't control what the JSON maps to, all you can do is control how you react to it, by testing what was returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard, generic way to handle JSON is roughly as follows:

```
NSObject* jsonResult = [serializedJSON allValues];
if ([jsonResult isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
   <handle NSArray>
}
else if ([jsonResult isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
   <handle NSDictionary>
}
else if ([jsonResult isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
   <handle NSNumber>
}
else if ([jsonResult isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
   <handle NSString>
}
else if (jsonResult == [NSNull null]) {
   <handle null>
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your a life saver! I knew there had to be some type of method to check the class, but I couldn't find any when I searched. Thank you again!

Comment: @MichaelKing -- And remember that JSON is recursive -- that each dictionary and array contains elements which may be further resolved in the same way.